# emplace_back causes link error on static constexpr member

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, constexpr, one-definition-rule

Why does `emplace_back` take a reference of the member that requires a definition? What is the difference between `emplace_back(integer literal)` and `emplace_back(static constexpr integer member)`?

If I switch to C++17, it compiles fine. I found that in C++17 static constexpr data members are implicitly [inlined](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0386r2.pdf). Does it mean the compiler implicitly creates a definition for them?

Example code:

```
class base {
    int n;
public:
    base(int n):n(n) {}
};

struct base_trait {
    static constexpr int n = 1;
};

int main(void) {
    vector<base> v;
    v.emplace_back(1);  // ok
    v.emplace_back(base_trait::n);  // link error with -std=c++14, ok with -std=c++17
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you said, `emplace_back` takes arguments by reference, so passing `base_trait::n` causes it to be [odr-used](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use).

> an object is odr-used if its value is read (unless it is a compile time constant) or written, its address is taken, or a reference is bound to it;

Before C++17, that means the definiton of `base_trait::n` is required here. But since C++17 the behavior changed, for [constexpr static data member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Constant_static_members) the out-of-class definition is not needed again.

> If a const `non-inline (since C++17)` static data member `or a constexpr static data member (since C++11)` is odr-used, a definition at namespace scope is still required, but it cannot have an initializer. `This definition is deprecated for constexpr data members (since C++17).`
>
> A static data member may be declared inline. An inline static data member can be defined in the class definition and may specify an initializer. It does not need an out-of-class definition. (since C++17)

Comment: So rvalue reference needs a definition as well as lvalue reference?

Comment: @mljli It causes the argument to be odr-used; it's same as lvalue-reference. Before C++17 that means the definition is required. Ater C++17 the definiton of static constexpr data member is not required again, so your code works fine with C++17.

Comment: @mljli Why do you expect rvalue ref to be different? When used, both are just normal references (lvalues).

Comment: @curiousguy I thought const lvalue reference and rvalue reference don't require a definition. And static const member can just be used as literal, i.e., without storage/address.

Comment: @mljli Can you post an simple example of a ref that you believe does/should/could *not* require a definition?

Comment: @curiousguy I thought that because I forgot that compiler constructs temporary variables when passing literals. Literals are not variables so they don't have a definition. Right?

Comment: @mljli Literals are really pure rvalues. They don't have an address or a lifetime. When referencing binding is required, the compiler will create a **temporary object** (it won't create a "variable").